# Assigning different binding for comboboxes using single datatable

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I am using 7 comboboxes and textboxes to display certain items.
I have the data in DataTable. So i bind the datatable to comboboxes and textboxes like

```
cmbIngredient1.DataSource = dt;
cmbIngredient1.DisplayMember = "Ingredient";
cmbIngredient1.ValueMember = "Ingredient";
txtTotalIngre1.DataBindings.Clear();
txtTotalIngre1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "No Of Pieces");

cmbIngredient2.DataSource = dt;
cmbIngredient2.DisplayMember = "Ingredient";
cmbIngredient2.ValueMember = "Ingredient";
txtTotalIngre2.DataBindings.Clear();
txtTotalIngre2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "No Of Pieces");

//Similar code for all 7 combobox and textboxes.//
```

the data is being displayed. But when i change in combobox1 other combobox items  also changing..

I want like this:   when combobox1 item is changed only textbox1 should change.
when comboxbox2 item changed only textbox2 should change.

Do i need to create separate datatable and bind to achieve this??

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the same datatable as `Binding` *and* `DataSource`? that seems like a mistake. What do you need to update, when the user selects a value from the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by copying the datatable to another instance of Datatable

```
DataTable dt2 = dt;  
cmbIngredient2.DataSource = dt2;
cmbIngredient2.DisplayMember = "Ingredient";
cmbIngredient2.ValueMember = "Ingredient";
txtTotalIngre2.DataBindings.Clear();
txtTotalIngre2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "No Of Pieces");
```